# shell command to get pixel size of an image

Tags: conversion, images, image-manipulation, gif

Is there a shell command that returns the pixel size of an image?

I'm trying to produce an animated gif starting from different gifs with different sizes using `convert` (e.g. `convert -delay 50 1.gif 2.gif -loop 0 animated.gif`).

The problem is that convert simply overlaps the images using the first image's size as the size of the animated gif, and since they have different sizes the result is a bit of a mess, with bits of the old frames showing under the new ones.

Comment: Related question: [Use mogrify to resize large files while ignoring small ones](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38943/use-mogrify-to-resize-large-files-while-ignoring-small-ones/38946#38946)

Comment: What is "pixel size"? Bits per pixel (depth) or pixel count?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

found a solution: `identify`, part of the imagemagick package, does exactly what I need

```
$ identify color.jpg 
> color.jpg JPEG 1980x650 1980x650+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 231KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Comment: Could you explain why I got multiple rows when I run `identify imagename.ico`? `Like todour.ico[0] ICO 32x32 32x32+0+0 4-bit sRGB 0.000u 0:00.000`
`todour.ico[1] ICO 16x16 16x16+0+0 4-bit sRGB 0.000u 0:00.000`
`todour.ico[2] ICO 48x48 48x48+0+0 8-bit sRGB 0.000u 0:00.000`

Comment: @roachsinai, `identify` does this for images with multiple resolutions and for animations. Your icon file contained 16x16, 32x32, & 48x48 sizes. Animations may also show placement offsets and durations, like `a.gif[0] GIF 163x130 163x130+0+0 8-bit sRGB 65c 0.000u 0:00.000` `a.gif[1] GIF 132x125 163x130+20+3 8-bit sRGB 65c 0.000u 0:00.000`

Comment: @HonoreDoktorr thank you so much!

Comment: If speed is of concern (or large image/s) I'd recommend using GraphicsMagick, a fork of ImageMagick, but so much faster and lower CPU usage. See Jerry Epas answer way down. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/176972/43139

Answer (score 97):

Rather than parsing the output of `identify` by eye, or by text utilities, you can use its `-format` option to output the width and height in whatever format suits you best. For example:

```
$ identify -format '%w %h' img.png
100 200
$ identify -format '%wx%h' img.png
100x200
```

A list of image properties that you can output can be found on [this page](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/escape.php), but for the question here, it seems all you need are `%w` and `%h`, which give the image's width and height, respectively, in pixels.

---

The flexibility afforded by `-format` came in handy for me in finding the largest images in terms of pixels, by outputting `%[fx:w*h]` for a number of images and sorting the output.

You might want to specify the `-ping` option if you're processing many images, using more complicated escapes, and want to make sure the program doesn't waste time loading the entire images. With simple escapes, `-ping` should be the default. More information on the choice between `-ping` and `+ping` can be found [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#identify_ping).

Answer (score 47):

you can just use the command "file" to get the informations you need:

```
~# file cha_2.png 
cha_2.png: PNG image data, 656 x 464, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
```

Comment: This does NOT report the size for other (non-png) image types... `file taylor-swift-money-makers-990.jpg` ->
`taylor-swift-money-makers-990.jpg: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, comment: "CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJ"`

Comment: Not true, it does under recent macOS versions at least.

Comment: Confirm png and jpg are supported by `file` (version 5.04 of the file command). Example: `$ file mlk.jpg` outputs `JPEG image data, baseline, precision 8, 960x801, components 3`

Answer (score 6):

You can also try [GraphicsMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/), which is a well maintained fork of ImageMagick used at e.g. Flickr and Etsy:

```
$ gm identify a.jpg
a.jpg JPEG 480x309+0+0 DirectClass 8-bit 25.2K 0.000u 0:01
```

It is faster than ImageMagick's identify (in my tests about twice).

Comment: Can't believe this isn't higher. Especially for larger images, im: 1.629s vs gm: 0.009s in my tests. In general GraphicsMagick is much faster, even ffmpeg can be, depending on your use case.

Answer (score 5):

**Use `identify` to see the sizes :**

```
$ identify color.jpg 
> color.jpg JPEG 1980x650 1980x650+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 231KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

**Extract value via `cut | sed`, from field 3:**

```
identify ./color.jpg | cut -f 3 -d " " | sed s/x.*// #width
identify ./color.jpg | cut -f 3 -d " " | sed s/.*x// #height
```

**Asign to variable:**

```
W=`identify ./color.jpg | cut -f 3 -d " " | sed s/x.*//` #width
H=`identify ./color.jpg | cut -f 3 -d " " | sed s/.*x//` #height
echo $W
> 1980
echo $H
> 650
```

Comment: genius. XDDDDDD

Answer (score 3):

Both `display` and `file` are quite slow, and have the potential to bring even quite capable systems to their knees dealing with many multiple files. A small test:

```
     $ du -h *.png --total | tail -n 1
     9.2M    total

     $ ls -l *.png | wc -l
     107

     $ /usr/bin/time file *.png
-->  0.37user 0.26system 0:06.93elapsed 9%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 37232maxresident)k
     22624inputs+0outputs (9major+2883minor)pagefaults 0swaps

     $ /usr/bin/time identify *.png
-->  0.56user 0.22system 0:06.77elapsed 11%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 25648maxresident)k
     34256inputs+0outputs (119major+2115minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

By reading only the bytes necessary, this operation can be significantly sped up.

```
     $ /usr/bin/time ./pngsize *.png
-->  0.00user 0.00system 0:00.03elapsed 12%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 1904maxresident)k
     0inputs+0outputs (0major+160minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

Here is pngsize:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <err.h>
#define oops(syscall) { printf("error processing %s: ", argv[i]); \
        fflush(0); perror(syscall"()"); continue; }
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int fd, i;
    uint32_t h, w;
    if (argc < 2) { printf("%s <pngfile> [pngfile ...]\n", argv[0]); exit(0); }
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        if (argc > 2) printf("%s: ", argv[i]);
        if ((fd = open(argv[i], O_RDONLY)) == -1) oops("open");
        if (lseek(fd, 16, SEEK_SET) == -1) oops("lseek");
        if (read(fd, &w, 4) < 1) oops("read");
        if (read(fd, &h, 4) < 1) oops("read");
        printf("%dx%d\n", htonl(w), htonl(h));
        if (close(fd) == -1) oops("close");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This method is *much* faster than using a library which loads the PNG forwards, backwards and sideways just to get the image size :P
(Consider the code carefully before feeding it a directory full of arbitrary PNGs of course.)

The code uses inet.h for [htonl()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/htonl) to de-[endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)-ize the header byte ordering.

Comment: Just a little note if you want to compile the above code. Save the C code above to `pngimage.c` then run the command ` gcc -o pngimage pngimage.c` this will create a command line executable called `pngimage` you can then call. You will need to hav Xcode installed on your system.

Answer (score 3):

This was a helpful snippet (I didn't write) that does returns dimensions for every png and jpg in the folder:

```
file ./* | perl -ne '@m = /^.*.jpg|^.*.png|[0-9][0-9]*[ ]?x[ ]?[0-9][0-9]*/g; print "@m\n"'
```

Answer (score 0):

For those like me who want the size in megapixels :

```bash
perl -le "printf \"=> fileName = %s size = %.2f Mpix\n\", \"$fileName\", $(identify -format '%w*%h/10**6' $fileName)"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been added to [act](https://github.com/lancejpollard/act):

```
$ npm install @lancejpollard/act -g
$ act read image.png --size

    2000x2000
```

Answer (score 0):

If performance is an issue, you can install w3m-img utilities and use it like this:

```
printf "5;%s" "/path/to/img.jpg" | "/usr/lib/w3m/w3mimgdisplay"
```