# Find and delete photos that are smaller than a certain dimension

Tags: files, find, images

I would like to loop through some directories with pictures and copy (and after reviewing remove) them to another directory based on image dimensions, let's say smaller than 800x600.

I've tried a query like

```
find . -iname "*.jpg" -type f -exec identify -format '%w %h %i' '{}' \; | awk '$1<800 || $2<600
```

but I get no results, but I'm certain that there are smaller pictures.

Can anyone give me a hint? Thanks!

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/1513618/432690

Comment: Possibly related [shell command to get pixel size of an image](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75635/shell-command-to-get-pixel-size-of-an-image)

Comment: What happens if you change the format string to `'%w %h %i\n'`? I think your entire output may get concatenated to one single line at the moment because the format doesn't specify that a new-line is to be printed at end-of-record, and if the very first picture found doesn't happen to be smaller than 800x600, the entire output will be discarded by `awk`.

Comment: Also, shouldn't it be `awk '$1<800 && $2<600'`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use mogrify to resize large files while ignoring small ones](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38943/use-mogrify-to-resize-large-files-while-ignoring-small-ones)