# How to batch resize all images in a folder (including subfolders)?

Tags: linux, images, batch-jobs

I have huge, 12GB, gallery on the server, full of images in various subfolders. Those files are too big and not used in full resolution. I need to resize all the images down to 820px wide (keeping proportions). So my question is - how can I create some kind of crawling script which would resize all images bigger then 820px and save them back overwriting original file?

Hope you can help me :-) Thank you in advance.

Comment: `find . -name "*.jpg" -exec mogrify -resize 820x  {} +` will do them all; if you don't want to process the "less than 820px" ones, there are some options [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/38943).

Answer (score 24):

ImageMagick tools `convert` or `mogrify` will do the job.

You can get them via your package manager or the source/rpms [here](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#unix).

Basic usage (will overwrite the original file):

```
$ mogrify -resize 820x ./*.jpg
```

If you need recursion:

```
find . -name '*.jpg' -execdir mogrify -resize 820x {} +
```

Comment: I don't think that "820px wide (keeping proportions)" means "resizing to 820x820". It's rather more like "820px wide and whatever-the-proportion-is high" ;) Plus this does not handle recursiveness.

Comment: Good point. Edited!

Comment: If you want to make it so that it only resizes if they are larger than set dimensions and still keep the ratios, you can change it to this: 

`find . -name '*.jpg' -execdir mogrify -resize '820x620>' {} \;`

Comment: Caution: This will overwrite your existing images.

Comment: Related: [How do I control the compression rate of mogrify?](https://superuser.com/q/79287/358758) (Super User)

Comment: Where's the `convert` example?

Comment: To only resize larger files, you can do `find . -size +200k -execdir ...` (only resize bigger than 200 kb+)