# Resizing/Processing only images in folder larger than specified height?

Tags: images, image-manipulation, mogrify

I have a folder with JPG images, some of which have a height dimension larger than 1900 pixels. I need a command that will ignore the images with a height dimension lower than 1900 pixels, while resizing only images with a greater height.

This command does the resizing job, but in the process it still opens and re-saves the images it doesn't resize, which eats up HD and CPU bandwidth:

`mogrify -resize 'x1900>' *.jpg`

Is there a better command, that will ignore the images that fall below the pixel threshold?

The question is different from the question here: [Use mogrify to resize large files while ignoring small ones](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38943/use-mogrify-to-resize-large-files-while-ignoring-small-ones)

I want the command to determine which JPGs are larger than a certain height, taking the width out of the equation.

Comment: @don_crissti This question isn't an exact duplicate, as I only want to determine which images have a larger height, taking the width out the equation.

Comment: Your problem is actually the same: _"this command does the resizing job, but in the process it still opens and re-saves the images it doesn't resize, which eats up HD and CPU bandwidth"_

Comment: @don_crissti The answers on that other thread answer that, but the solutions they provide use both width and height. I only want the height of the images to be determined. Can I open a new question asking how to modify one of the answers on the other thread to determine only height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `zsh`

```
higher() {
  local h
  h=$(identify -format %h - < $REPLY) &&
    ((h > $1))
}

mogrify -resize 'x1900>' ./*.jpg(.e:higher 1900:)
```