# Bulk Resize images in sub directories with Imagemagick

Tags: images, imagemagick, image-manipulation

I'm trying to resize all images in a directory and sub directories.
I have this script which I got from here: [Use mogrify to resize large files while ignoring small ones](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38943/use-mogrify-to-resize-large-files-while-ignoring-small-ones)

and adjusted to:

```
identify -format '%w %h %i\n' ./*.jpg |
awk '$1 > 1200 || $2 > 1200 {sub(/^[^ ]* [^ ]* /, ""); print}' |
tr '\n' '\0' |
xargs -0 mogrify -resize '1200x1200'
```

but it only does the current directory and only .jpg extensions - ignores the upper case - .JPG

I've tried making adjustments but not making much progress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could combine `identify` with [`find`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find), for example:

```
find . -type f -iname "*.jpg" -exec identify -format '%w %h %i\n' {} \;
```

which will run your `identify` command for every file recursively found with name ending in .jpg (case-insensitive).

Using your full example:

```
find . -type f -iname "*.jpg" -exec identify -format '%w %h %i\n' {} \; |
awk '$1 > 1200 || $2 > 1200 {sub(/^[^ ]* [^ ]* /, ""); print}' |
tr '\n' '\0' |
xargs -0 mogrify -resize '1200x1200'
```

Comment: Awesome - works perfectly!
In second code block just update the file extension to .jpg

Comment: I have just tried this same script on another server but just get the error:

find: `identify': No such file or directory

Comment: Is imagemagick installed?

Comment: Yes it is installed
Trying again and get loads of the above error message and this at the bottom:
xargs: mogrify: No such file or directory

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Try running just `identify` and `mogrify` to see if you get `command not found`, in which case there is a problem with your imagemagick install.

Comment: Might be something like that alright ran: 
`mogrify -resize 50% 1test.jpg` and 
`magick mogrify -resize 50% 1test.jpg` 
First one said mogrify can be found on one of following packages and other one said no command 'magick' found. It was installed via [https://serverpilot.io/community/articles/how-to-install-the-php-imagemagick-extension.html](https://serverpilot.io/community/articles/how-to-install-the-php-imagemagick-extension.html)

Comment: Ah - sorted now - installed via [https://serverpilot.io/community/articles/how-to-install-the-imagemagick-executable.html](https://serverpilot.io/community/articles/how-to-install-the-imagemagick-executable.html)